# C++: ¿Porqué me lanza error al llamar a un método de esta forma?

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de llamar a un método de una clase pero me lanza un error.

Error: `[Error] request for member 'Area' in '*(((Polygon**)(& Polygons)) + ((sizetype)(((long long unsigned int)i) * 8ull)))', which is of pointer type 'Polygon*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)`

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Polygon.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Triangle.h"


/**/

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Polygon* Polygons[2];

    Polygons[0] = new Rectangle(7,4);
    Polygons[1] = new Triangle(3,4,4);

    for(int i = 0;i<2;i++){
        std::cout<<"Area: "<<(Polygons+i)->Area()<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Perimetro: "<<(Polygons+i)->Perimeter()<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Polygon es una clase abstracta con 2 métodos:

`Perimeter()` y `Area()`, son para obtener el área y el perímetro respectivamente.
`Rectangle` y `Triangle` son 2 clases hijas con las cuales estoy trabajando el polimorfismo.

¿Porqué me lanza el error al llamar al método de la siguiente manera `(Polygons+i)->Area()`?

En el siguiente código no me lanza ese error:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Posicion.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Posicion* Coordenadas = new Posicion[2];

    Coordenadas[0] = Posicion(2,2);
    Coordenadas[1] = Posicion(1,2);

    for(int i = 0;i<2;i++){
        std::cout<<"X: "<<(Coordenadas+i)->getX()<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Y: "<<(Coordenadas+i)->getY()<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

¿Porqué ahí si me deja hacer uso del método de esta forma `(Arreglo+indice)->metodo()` y en la primera no?

¿Cual es la diferencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La diferencia está en la declaración de la formación:

```
Polygon* Polygons[2];
```

y

```
Posicion* Coordenadas = new Posicion[2];
```

El primero es una formación de dos punteros a objetos de tipo `Polygon` y el siguiente es una formación de dos objetos de tipo `Polygon`.

Una formación es un puntero a su primer elemento y se puede escribir de nuevo la primera declaración como:

```
Polygon** Polygons = new Polygon*[2];
```

Entonces puedes ver que el tipo de expresión `Polygons+i` es `Polygon**` en vez de `Polygon*` y tienes que utilizar el operador `*` para resolver tu problema:

```
(*(Polygons+i))->Perimeter()
```

Esto parece un poco feo. Recordamos que `*(Polygons+i)` y `Polygons[i]` es lo mismo, así que la solución final es:

```
Polygons[i]->Perimeter()
```

Comment: "y el siguente es una formación de dos objetos de tipo Polygon." seria 2 objetos de tipo Posicion no?

Comment: @Franco En el primero se crea un **array de punteros** en la cual cada puntero apunta a un objeto de tipo `Polygon`. En el segundo se crea un **array de objetos** de tipo `Posicion`. La diferencia es que en el primero, el identificador `Polygons` es simplemente un alias de la dirección base (la dirección de memoria del primer puntero) del **array de punteros** y en el segundo, el identificador `Coordenadas` es un puntero que apunta a la primera dirección de memoria del **array de objetos**.